# Meaning of the word "peg" in contex

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/Bw8g_1VEEL8). It is at 10 minute and 56 second.

> Before the Euro was introduced, they **pegged** their own currency.

Comment: Is the "vide" empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made an error in transcription; what the video says is:

> Before the Euro was introduced, they [Belgium and Luxembourg] **pegged** their *old currencies*.

What's missing is an implied "to each other" at the end of the sentence.  In the context of **pegging** a currency, it's always **pegged to** something.

When a country **pegs** its currency **to** another currency, it means that the first country fixes its exchange rate to be a constant value that never changes, regardless of financial situation in that country.  Most often, it's a poorer country **pegging to** a more stable currency from a rich country in an attempt to borrow some of that rich country's fiscal stability.  For example, Bulgaria has pegged its *lev* to the Euro at a rate of 0.51 (and before the Euro, it was pegged to the German mark), meaning that no matter what crazy stuff might go on in Bulgaria, its currency is no less stable than the Euro itself.

Note that the opposite of a **pegged** currency is a **floating** currency.  That is, it's allowed to "float" up or down with the rising or lowering (metaphorical) tide of the economy.

In your video, it is an unusual case where two stable, first-world countries mutually decided to **peg** their currencies **to each other**, meaning that they were exchanged at a fixed rate.  Here, there was no "poor" partner and no "rich" partner - it's two relatively rich countries whose economies were so intertwined that they decided that they could be even more prosperous if they eliminated the friction and annoyance of a floating exchange rate.

Answer (score 2):

A currency peg is a governmental policy of fixing the exchange rate of its currency to that of another currency, or occasionally to the gold price.